# How to get duplicate values from a list of dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and I am trying to separate duplicate keys from my list of dictionary. Find the list below

```
dataList = [{'Key': 'US', 'Val': 'NewYork'},
 {'Key': 'Aus', 'Val': 'Sydney'}, 
 {'Key': 'US', 'Val': 'Washington'}, 
 {'Key': 'Ind', 'Val': 'Delhi'}, 
 {'Key': 'Fra', 'Val': 'Paris'},
 {'Key': 'Ind', 'Val': 'Chennai'}]
```

I would like to fetch duplicate keys and its values

Expected Result

```
duplicates = [{'Key': 'Ind', 'Val': 'Delhi'},{'Key': 'Ind', 'Val': 'Chennai'},{'Key': 'US', 'Val': 'NewYork'},{'Key': 'US', 'Val': 'Washington'}]
nonduplicate = [{'Key': 'Aus', 'Val': 'Sydney'},{'Key': 'Fra', 'Val': 'Paris'}]
```

Find below my sample code, it does not give me desired output

```
uniqueValues = []
duplicateValues = []
# Creating a list of all duplicate values in dictionary
for attribute in dataList:
    for k, v in attribute.items():
        if v not in uniqueValues :
            uniqueValues.append(v)
        else:    
            duplicateValues.append(v)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: That's because the *whole* dictionaries are not duplicates. Only the `Key` values are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your dictionaries are not duplicates as a whole, you are defining them as unique by the value of `Key` only, so `v not in uniqueValues` won't find `{'Key': 'US', 'Val': 'NewYork'}` when you test with `{'Key': 'US', 'Val': 'Washington'}`.

Note that even if `v not in uniqueValues` was the correct test, you'd have added `{'Key': 'US', 'Val': 'NewYork'}` to `uniqueValues` already, and would have to remove it again and move it to `duplicateValues` the moment you find proof that it was a duplicate.

Instead, to divide the dictionaries into two buckets, you need to count the `'Key'` values *first* so you know if there is just one of a given value, or more:

```
from collections import Counter

key_counts = Counter(d['Key'] for d in dataList)

uniqueValues = []
duplicateValues = []
for d in dataList:
    if key_counts[d['Key']] == 1:
        uniqueValues.append(d)
    else:
        duplicateValues.append(d)
```

Don't be tempted to skip the counting loop, while you *can* count `d['Key']` values in a `for d in dataList:` loop too, you'd repeat that count for duplicate keys several times, *and* you would have to loop over all of `dataList` for every item in `dataList`, giving your code a *quadratic* amount of work to do, or O(N^2) in [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). By counting *first*, the amount of work only grows linearly, or O(N).

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> dataList = [{'Key': 'US', 'Val': 'NewYork'},
...  {'Key': 'Aus', 'Val': 'Sydney'},
...  {'Key': 'US', 'Val': 'Washington'},
...  {'Key': 'Ind', 'Val': 'Delhi'},
...  {'Key': 'Fra', 'Val': 'Paris'},
...  {'Key': 'Ind', 'Val': 'Chennai'}]
>>> key_counts = Counter(d['Key'] for d in dataList)
>>> key_counts
Counter({'US': 2, 'Ind': 2, 'Aus': 1, 'Fra': 1})
>>> uniqueValues = []
>>> duplicateValues = []
>>> for d in dataList:
...     if key_counts[d['Key']] == 1:
...         uniqueValues.append(d)
...     else:
...         duplicateValues.append(d)
...
>>> pprint(uniqueValues)
[{'Key': 'Aus', 'Val': 'Sydney'}, {'Key': 'Fra', 'Val': 'Paris'}]
>>> pprint(duplicateValues)
[{'Key': 'US', 'Val': 'NewYork'},
 {'Key': 'US', 'Val': 'Washington'},
 {'Key': 'Ind', 'Val': 'Delhi'},
 {'Key': 'Ind', 'Val': 'Chennai'}]
```